# Not listing .gitkeep file in tree listing command and also unrecognized charset

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, tree

For some reason when I execute this script i created the file `.gitkeep` does not show in the tree output and also my declaration of UTF8 for charset is incorrect.

Here is my current script code:

```
#!/bin/bash    

echo "Type in directory path to tree"

read directoryPath

tree -a -l -f -L 5 -P --charset UTF8 -h --device --dirsfirst -C $directoryPath
```

Here is my command and output

```
root@selector:/var/www/selector-skeleton-application# ./scripts/tree-directory.sh 
Type in directory path to tree
/var/www/selector-skeleton-application/lib/pluto/src
/var/www/selector-skeleton-application/lib/pluto/src
0 directories, 0 files
```

However, here is a general directory listing command output

```
root@selector:/var/www/selector-skeleton-application# cd lib/pluto/src/
root@selector:/var/www/selector-skeleton-application/lib/pluto/src# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 01:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb  6 01:01 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  6 01:06 .gitkeep
root@selector:/var/www/selector-skeleton-application/lib/pluto/src#
```

And lastly, this is also being displayed in the output with the script i created:

```
UTF8 [error opening dir]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular combination of options: `-P --charset UTF8` does not make sense. `-P` is used for setting a pattern for directories that [`tree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tree.1.html) should print:

```
-P pattern
      List  only  those files that match the wild-card pattern.
```

You have set the pattern to `--charset`, which `.gitkeep` does not match, of course. That leaves `UTF8` as a non-option argument, which `tree` interprets as a directory name, hence the error you get.